# Show the selected index Item from DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have 2 form pages, the first page(default page) is including my data gridview, I can show lot of data in my data gridview.

when I double click on an Item in my data gridview for example (row = 1000) the second form will appear which is for editing,

when I press Edit button in the second page the First page will appear ,

**how can I handle** -->** that the index of Gridview be on the row which I selected for editing (row = 1000)

Comment: Its better to say When the first form will appear (load) after press edit button in second page, I dont wanna scroll all data to reach row = 1000 , I want when I edit that row after loading first page I wanna see my datagridview's index on row=1000

Answer (score 2):

Try for **FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex** property of grid view like

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

This will select your one particular row.
For more details Visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)

**Solution for argumentOtOfRangeException error**

For solving this problem make sure that all the rows of datagridview have the same width and height otherwise the

> FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

causing problem.

Hope it works.

Comment: I did this but the problem is, I wanna use this code on my Form load

when I run the application it shows me an error "ArgumentOutOfRengException"

Comment: may you please tell me that how you assign that code on Form Load

Comment: if you directly assign value to FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex then this error is coming or not,,plz check and tell me.

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label4.Text = currentdata.ToString();
            
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[iRow].Cells[iCol];
            if (dgv_data.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
            { 
            dgv_data.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentdata;
            dgv_data.Refresh();
            dgv_data.CurrentCell = dgv_data.Rows[currentdata].Cells[0];
            dgv_data.Rows[currentdata].Selected = true;}

Comment: My data in my database is around 10000 data, but when I select row number 800 the error will appear ... mention that the Currentdata here is 800

if you select row number 300 the currentdata will be 300

Comment: just set dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 800; and check that is it working or again giving error, but only use this line..

Comment: ok try this instead of your code and tell what happen int currentdata = 1000;
 
           dgv_data.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentdata;
           dgv_data.Refresh();
           dgv_data.CurrentCell = dgv_data.Rows[currentdata].Cells[0];
           dgv_data.Rows[currentdata].Selected = true;

Comment: I tried this before... now I try it again and I have same erroe "argumentOtOfRangeException"

Comment: do you mind if you give me your email I will send you the picture of my error ??

here my reputation is low and does not let me to publish a pic

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to directly scroll to you desired location

```
// index is your poistion ie 1000
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = index;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
dataGrid.CurrentCell = dataGrid.Rows[index].Cells[0];
dataGrid.Rows[index].Selected = true;
```

Comment: I got this error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."

Comment: I did this
 int currentdata = 1000;
 dgv_data.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentdata;
            dgv_data.Refresh();
            dgv_data.CurrentCell = dgv_data.Rows[currentdata].Cells[0];
            dgv_data.Rows[currentdata].Selected = true;

then I got this error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values"

Comment: @Kamal Mandavi The specified value when setting this property is should be greater than 0 or less than the number of rows in the control minus 1. so if you have 1000 rows set index value to 999